# TCL and NS2 "error when calling class $cls: $args: $args"

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have looked on line however i have been unable to debug my issue.
I am running a tcl file and it will produce the following error, i have hard coded the values and it still wont work. Why does it not like the nametrace line?

```
set val(rp)     AODV                       ;# routing protocol
set opt(x)      3500
set opt(y)      2000


set ns_     [new Simulator]
set tracefd     [open map.tr w]
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd

set namf [open map.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-allwireless $namf opt(x) opt(y)
```

Running the code above generates the following error

```
(_o3 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o3 cmd namtrace-allwireless file4 3500 2000"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o3" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$ns_ namtrace-allwireless $namf $opt(x) $opt(y)"
    (file "map.tcl" line 45)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why the error is being thrown and what steps i could take to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Your report neatly omits the actual error message, and just gives the stack trace. Unfortunately, for oTcl (the object system that NS2 uses) the stack trace isn't very informative; it just tells us that the problem occurred inside the implementation of the `namtrace-allwireless` method of the `Simulator` class, or perhaps that it occurred when trying to dispatch to the implementation. Hard to say which. ***You need to fix your error reporting.***

## Error reporting from C and C++

If you've written the implementation of the method in C or C++, the most likely issue would be that you've not set the Tcl interpreter result to an error message on the particular path that is returning `TCL_ERROR` in this case. The standard Tcl API helper functions all set that up when they detect an error (though in some cases only if asked via the `TCL_LEAVE_ERR_MSG` flag; this applies to the variable accessors) but for errors that you generate yourself because there's some condition that you've detected, you need to do it “by hand” by calling `Tcl_SetResult` or `Tcl_SetObjResult` or `Tcl_AppendResult`.

## Error reporting from Tcl

If you've written the implementation of the method in Tcl, the problem is probably that you've done this, using the default empty result:

```
return -code error
```

Add an error message at the end:

```
return -code error "something bad happened"
```

Or use the `error` command which forces you to supply a message (and don't use an empty string for it).

---

The actual cause of your problem is unknown. I *suspect* that it's either resolving a variable in the wrong stack context (and you've not asked the code to generate an error for you when that happens) or a case where it'll be obvious once you fix your error reporting. Getting errors right is important.